# JS Paintbrush color on HTML canvas won't work

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, colors, paint

I am trying to build a basic paint program in Javascript using html canvases, but I'm having a problem changing the brush color when running the code in firefox (it works fine in Chrome). Below is my html, css and javascript. If you could tell me how to make the colors change in firefox it would help a lot.

HTML:

```
    <div id="controls">

        <div id="tools" class="container">
            <div id="tool-images">
                <img id="pencil" src="Images/tools/pencil.png">
                <img id="eraser" src="Images/tools/eraser.png">
                <img id="paintBucket" src="Images/tools/paintBucket.png">
                <img id="hand" src="Images/tools/hand.png">
            </div>
            <p class="name">Tools</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tool-size" class="container">
            <p><label>Size:</label>
            <input type="number" id="tool-size-input" value="12" min="0"></p>
            <p class="name">Tool size</p>
        </div>

        <div id="color" class="container">
            <input type="color">
            <p class="name">Color</p>
        </div>

        <div id="u/d" class="container">
            <p><input type="button" id="saveButton" value="Save"></p>
            <p><input type="button" id="uploadButton" value="Upload"></p>
            <p class="name">File</p>
        </div>

        <div id="layers" class="container">
            <p><input type="button" id="new-layer" value="New"></p>
            <p><input type="button" id="remove-layer" value="Remove"></p>
            <p class="name">Layers</p>
        </div>

<div id="selection" class="container">
            <p>

            <input type="number" id="select-layer" value="0" min="0" max="0"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="layerThumbNails">
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="canvases">
        <canvas id="front-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <div id="insert"></div>
        <canvas id="back-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <canvas id="compCan" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #D2DBE9;
    user-select: none;
height: 90%;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

/*------------Controls-------------*/

#controls, #properties{
    color: #663977;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #DCE6F4;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #C5CFDF;
}

.container{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    height:80px;
    width:100px;
    border-right:1px solid #A5B8D0;
}

#layerThumbNails{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    height:80px;
}

.thumbNail {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin:5px 20px 5px 0;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:white;
}

input[type="button"], input[type="file"]{
    width:86px;
}

input[type="number"]{
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
}

input[type="color"]{
    widows:50px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px 0 0 12px;
}

#controls .name{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    right:20px;
    font:12px Arial;
    color:#9883A9;
}

#tool-images img{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:25px;
    margin:1px;
}

#tool-images img:hover, .tool-active {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

/*------------canvases----------------*/

#canvases{
    position:relative;
    margin:5px 0 0 5px;
}

#canvases:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#back-canvas{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background-color:white;
}

#front-canvas{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

#compCan{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

/*-------------properties--------------*/

#properties{
    position:fixed;
    right:5px;
    width:130px;
    height:150px;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    display:none;
}

#properties input[type="number"]{
    margin-right:5px;
    width:60px;
}

#properties-title{
    text-align:center;
}

#invert{
    width:120px;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
var canvasFront = document.getElementById('front-canvas'),
    canvasBack = document.getElementById('back-canvas'),
    ctx = [];

var comp = document.getElementById('compCan'),
    ctxComp = comp.getContext('2d'),
    saveBtn = document.getElementById('saveButton'),
    uploadBtn = document.getElementById('uploadButton');

var canvasArr = [],
    canvasArrThumbNails = [],
    ctxThumbNails = [],
    newLayer = document.getElementById('new-layer'),
    removeLayer = document.getElementById('remove-layer'),
    layerSelector = document.getElementById('select-layer'),
    layerSelect = 0;

var canvasPosition;

var mouseX, mouseY, mouseXDown, mouseYDown, cX, cY,
    mouseXl = document.getElementById('mouseX'),
    mouseYl = document.getElementById('mouseY');

var tools = [];

tools.pencil = document.getElementById('pencil');
tools.eraser = document.getElementById('eraser');
tools.bucket = document.getElementById('paintBucket');
tools.hand = document.getElementById('hand');

var toolSize = document.getElementById('tool-size-input'),
    activeColor;

var eraserCursor = "url(images/cursor/small_eraser.png), pointer",
    pencilCursor = "url(images/cursor/pencil.png), pointer";

/*var canvasClear = document.getElementById('clear-canvas'),
    fileImg = document.getElementById('img-file'),
    properties = document.getElementById('properties'),
    imgWidth = document.getElementById('img-width'),
    imgHeight = document.getElementById('img-height');*/

/*var startX = 100, startY = 100;*/

window.onload = function() {
    canvasPosition = canvasBack.getBoundingClientRect();
}

canvasFront.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPosition.left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPosition.top;
    /*mouseXl.innerHTML = mouseX;
    mouseYl.innerHTML = mouseY;*/
}


/*------------tools selection-------------*/

addAllHandlers(tools, "tool-active");

function addAllHandlers(arr, className){
    for (var item in arr) {
        arr[item].onmousedown = addHandler(arr[item], arr, className);
    }
}

function addHandler(element, arr, className) {
    return function() {
        removeAllClasses(arr);
        element.setAttribute("class", className);
    }
}

function removeAllClasses(arr) {
    for (var item in arr) {
        arr[item].removeAttribute("class");
    }
}


/*----------save-----------------*/

saveBtn.onclick = function() {
    ctxComp.clearRect(0,0,comp.width, comp.height);
    for (var item in canvasArr){
        ctxComp.drawImage(canvasArr[item], canvasArr[item].offsetLeft, canvasArr[item].offsetTop);
    }
}

uploadBtn.onclick = function() {

    alert("yay");
}

/*----------layers---------------*/

layerSelector.onchange = function() {
    layerSelect = layerSelector.value-1;
}

/*canvasArrThumbNails[].onmouseover = function() {
    window.alert("");
}//rtghjdfhjghfg*/

newLayer.onclick = function() {
    canvasArr.push("layer" + canvasArr.length);
    canvasArrThumbNails.push("layer" + canvasArrThumbNails.length);
    selectorRefresh();

    canvasArr[layerSelect] = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasArr[layerSelect].style.position = "absolute";
    canvasArr[layerSelect].width = 500;
    canvasArr[layerSelect].height = 500;
    canvasArr[layerSelect].style.background = "none";
    canvasArr[layerSelect].style.zIndex = canvasArr.length+1;

    canvasArrThumbNails[layerSelect] = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasArrThumbNails[layerSelect].className = "thumbNail";
    document.getElementById('layerThumbNails').appendChild(canvasArrThumbNails[layerSelect]);

    canvasFront.style.zIndex = canvasArr.length+2;
    document.getElementById('insert').appendChild(canvasArr[layerSelect]);

    ctx[layerSelect] = canvasArr[layerSelect].getContext('2d');
    ctxThumbNails[layerSelect] = canvasArrThumbNails[layerSelect].getContext('2d');
    ctxThumbNails[layerSelect].scale(0.6,0.3);

    ctx[layerSelect].strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx[layerSelect].strokeText(layerSelect + 1, 5, 12);
}

removeLayer.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('insert').removeChild(canvasArr[layerSelect]);
    canvasArr.splice(layerSelect, 1);
    ctx.splice(layerSelect, 1);
    canvasFront.style.zIndex = canvasArr.length+2;

    document.getElementById('layerThumbNails').removeChild(canvasArrThumbNails[layerSelect]);
    canvasArrThumbNails.splice(layerSelect, 1);
    ctxThumbNails.splice(layerSelect, 1);
    cleanArray(canvasArrThumbNails);
    cleanArray(canvasArr);
    cleanArray(ctx);
    cleanArray(ctxThumbNails);

    selectorRefresh();
}

function selectorRefresh() {
    layerSelect = canvasArr.length-1;
    layerSelector.value = canvasArr.length;
    layerSelector.max = layerSelect+1;
}

function cleanArray(actual){
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++){
        if (actual[i]){
            newArray.push(actual[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

/*------------paint---------------*/

var processing = false;
var operations = [];

canvasFront.onmouseover = function(){
    if (tools.eraser.active){
        this.style.cursor = "url(images/cursor/small_eraser.png), pointer";
    }
    else if (tools.pencil.active){
        this.style.cursor = "url(images/cursor/pencil.png), pointer";
    }
    else if (tools.hand.active){
        this.style.cursor = "url(images/cursor/hand.png), pointer";
    }
    else { this.style.cursor = auto;}
}

operations['mousedown'] = function() {
    processing = true;
    ctx[layerSelect].beginPath();
    mouseXDown = mouseX;
    mouseYDown = mouseY;
    cX = canvasArr[layerSelect].offsetLeft;
    cY = canvasArr[layerSelect].offsetTop;
};
operations['mouseup'] = function() {
    processing = false;

    thumbNailUpdate();
};
operations['mouseout'] = function(){
    processing = false;

    thumbNailUpdate();
};

canvasFront.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {operations["mousedown"]()});

canvasFront.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {operations["mouseup"]()});

canvasFront.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {operations["mousemove"]()});

canvasFront.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {operations["mouseout"]()});

tools.pencil.onclick = function() {
    for (var item in tools){
        tools[item].active = false;
    }
    tools.pencil.active = true;
    operations['mousemove'] = function() {
        if (processing){
            fillCircle(mouseX - cX, mouseY - cY, toolSize.value);
        };
    };
};

tools.eraser.onclick = function() {
    for (var item in tools){
        tools[item].active = false;
    }
    tools.eraser.active = true;
    operations['mousemove'] = function() {
        if (processing){
            clearCircle(mouseX - cX, mouseY - cY, toolSize.value);
        };
    };
};

tools.hand.onclick = function() {
    for (var item in tools){
        tools[item].active = false;
    }
    tools.hand.active = true;
    operations['mousemove'] = function() {
        moveCanvas();
    };
};

function thumbNailUpdate(){
    ctxThumbNails[layerSelect].clearRect(0,0,70, 70);
    ctxThumbNails[layerSelect].drawImage(canvasArr[layerSelect],0,0);
}

function moveCanvas() {
    if (processing){
        canvasArr[layerSelect].style.left = mouseX + cX - mouseXDown + "px";
        canvasArr[layerSelect].style.top = mouseY + cY - mouseYDown + "px";
    }
}


function fillCircle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx[layerSelect].fillStyle = activeColor;
    ctx[layerSelect].beginPath();
    ctx[layerSelect].arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx[layerSelect].fill();
}

function clearCircle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx[layerSelect].save();
    ctx[layerSelect].globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx[layerSelect].beginPath();
    ctx[layerSelect].arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx[layerSelect].fill();
    ctx[layerSelect].restore();
}

color.onchange = function(e) {
    activeColor = e.srcElement.value;
}
```

Again, any help that could be offered would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You are more likely to get help if your code works. Try creating a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) that works in chrome. I'm also not clear on what Firefox is doing wrong. A better description of the error you are seeing in Firefox would really help. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as a good starting point for how to ask a great question.

Comment: Firefox doesn't output an error, it just won't change the brush color.

Comment: Again, you really need a working example of the problem. If you create a fully functional demo in jsfiddle.net then people are more likely to help. No one wants to spend their time reading code that doesn't even work.